# what function to use in glm to get the same result as this function

Tags: opengl, glm-math

There is a function `GLRotation`

```
inline const mat4 GLRotation(float x, float y, float z)
{
    const float cx = cosf(x * math_radians), sx = sinf(x * math_radians),
                cy = cosf(y * math_radians), sy = sinf(y * math_radians),
                cz = cosf(z * math_radians), sz = sinf(z * math_radians);

    // rotationX * rotationY * rotationZ
    return mat4(cy * cz, -cy * sz, sy, 0,
                cx * sz + sx * cz * sy, cx * cz - sx * sy * sz, -cy * sx, 0,
                sx * sz - cx * cz * sy, cz * sx + cx * sy * sz, cx * cy, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

And use can call it like this `GLRotation(v.rotation)` where `v.rotation` - vector(x, y, z).

What function I need to use in `glm`(library) to get the same result?

Comment: glm::rotate should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `GLRotation()` specifies the angle in radians to rotate in each principle axis. On the other hand `glm::rotate(angle, axis)` specifies a rotation about a provided axis. So, strictly speaking you can define your `GLRotation` as follows:

```
inline mat4 
GLRotation(float x, float y, float z)
{
    return 
        glm::rotate(x, 1, 0, 0) * 
        glm::rotate(y, 0, 1, 0) * 
        glm::rotate(z, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Although I wouldn't advise this, because describing rotations in this way can lead to [Gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) (when you rotate in one axis in such a way that it becomes aligned with another axis, losing you one degree of freedom).

Better to look into [Axis-Angle representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) of rotations, which is what `glm::rotate` uses. They aren't susceptible to gimbal lock, and can represent any 3D rotation about an axis through the origin.

Comment: Oh! I see.  I used this because I had to check whether the results are the same.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following to get a rotaion using glm, although it requires slightly more input:

```
glm::rotate(ModelViewProjectionMatrix4x4Here,angleToRotateHere,directionToRotate)
```

which follows the format layed out in [the glm api page](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00206.html)

```
rotate (detail::tmat4x4< T > const &m, T angle, T x, T y, T z)
```

so you can pass it the matrix you need to operate on, the angle to rotate by and the vector around which to rotate.

```
glm::rotate(yourMatrixHere, angle_in_degrees, glm::vec3(x, y, z)); // where x, y, z is axis of rotation (e.g. 0 1 0 is rotate around the y-axis)
```

If that exact function definition does not match what you need there are others on the same web-page which take arguments in varying ways.

Let me know if you need any more information:)

Comment: I don't understand how the function works. I mean in `glm` it require angle to rotate a vector. But there - there is no angle in input? or `math_radians` is the angle because it has declaration `const float math_radians = math_pi / 180.0f;`

Comment: Hi,  I have added in another line to explain the usage a little better as well:)

Comment: I see. But in original usage it was `mat4 view           = GLRotation(camera.rotation) * GLTranslation(-camera.position);` so with glm it will look like this - `mat4 view = rotate(math_radians, camera.rotation) * translate(-camera.position);` because there is also `rotate` method without matrix as input